How to prevent a Telegram bot from stopping on Render?
I have programmed a Telegram bot using Python and deployed it on Render. I am also using Amazon S3 to save my data. The idea of my bot is to send scheduled messages to multiple groups, but I have an issue: every 15 minutes, Render puts my bot to sleep, and when the scheduled time comes, my bot doesn't send any messages.
Each time, I need to manually send a message to my bot to "wake it up" about 10 minutes before the scheduled time to make sure it sends the data. This is really difficult for me since I have around 50 groups throughout the week that require sending messages at specific times.
I tried to solve this problem using the following code, but it hasn't worked:
asyncio.run(set_webhook())

async def keep_awake():
    while True:
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(f"{WEBHOOK_URL}/check_webhook") as response:
                    if response.status == 200:
                        logger.info("App is awake.")
                    else:
                        logger.warning(f"Received unexpected status code: {response.status}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error sending keep-awake request: {e}")
        
        await asyncio.sleep(600)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(keep_awake())
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, loop=loop)

